# How to completely remove a google/gmail connected app?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

When I open an attached document (txt file, google document, microsoft word file etc.), at the very top I have `Open with` option. There is a list of `Connected apps`. I want to remove one of them from that list (and completely remove it).

I removed its access as the guide instructs here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en
but it still shows it as I described above.

When I click on `Open with` and then choose `+ Connect more apps`, search for that app, click on it to see more details it shows there a green button `Connected`. When I press it nothing happens and it seems like it is disabled because there is a similar share button that looks similar that when I hover over it with the mouse it changes the green color a bit to indicate it's pressable.

How do I completely remove/unattach that app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Google Drive at https://drive.google.com
Click the gear/cog icon and choose Settings
In the left column of the pop-up, choose Manage apps
From there you can remove any apps that you no longer want to use